# Why can a vector be removed from surface by small enough change to one of its components, for at least $n-k$ components?

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces

During my math studies, I got this question. I tried to solve it for a few days but didn't succeed.

Let $M$ be a $ k $-dimension surface in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$, $(1 \le k \lt n)$ and $x \in M$.

I need to prove that there is $\delta \gt 0$ and (at least) $ n - k $ different indexes $1 \le i_1 , i_2, \dots , i_{n-k} \leq n $ such that for all $ 0 \lt |t| \lt \delta $, $ x + t e_{i_j} \notin M $ (for all $1 \le j \le n - k$).

i.e. $\{e_1, \dots ,e_n\}$ is the stardard basis of ${\mathbb{R}}^n$.

Does anyone have an idea of how can I prove this? ($M$ is a smooth surface)

Comment: Didn't you forget some smoothness condition? The surface of a hypercube dos not have the desired property

Comment: Yes, M is a smooth surface @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: The question reduces to prove that if we are given $k$ independent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$, then there exists $n-k$ canonical vectors $e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_{n-k}}$ such that $v_1,\dots,v_k,e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_{n-k}}$ are independents. To prove this you can use induction: $k=1$ is not hard, and then you go on replacing vectors $e_i$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I know how to prove the theorem you wrote, but I don't understand how my question reduces to this theorem. Can you please explain it? @user90189

Comment: Suppose that $0\in M$ and suppose that $\psi:U\subset\mathbb{R}^k\to M$ is a chart around $0$. Take $v_i := \partial_i\psi(0)$ and assume that $\{v_1,\dots,v_k,e_{k+1},\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis —if not, renumber the coordinates; then define the map $\Psi(y) = (\psi, y_{k+1},\dots,y_n)$ and use the Inverse Function Theorem.